# Cocoa icon in title bar

Tags: cocoa, interface

i want to set the icon in the title bar to the icon of the application

```
[[myWindow standardWindowButton:NSWindowDocumentIconButton] 
setImage:[NSApp applicationIconImage]];
```

however, nothing shows up in the title bar, just the text tile

the application icon is an .icns and displayed correctly in dock, finder, etc...

search also for a way in interface builder to set the icon, but looks like you cant do that in interface builder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The convention is that the window title bar has an icon **only when the window represents a file**.  Don't put an icon there in any other case. Look around various apps, they don't have icons.

If your window represents a file, use [`-[NSWindow setRepresentedFilename:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCICGFJC) or [`-[NSWindow setTitleWithRepresentedFilename:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BABDDGGB). They automatically set the icon in the title bar as is suitable for the file.

The icon set this way is known as a proxy icon, because you can drag it from the title bar and the icon behaves as if it is the file.

Comment: +1 for "Do not do this, it's not the way a window is supposed to behave if it doesn't represent a file."

Comment: @Joshua Thanks. I strongly disagree with the looks of Lion's address book and iCal, as you would guess :)

Comment: I think they're a little overdone, yes. :-) Subtle and tasteful changes to standard controls, if done without obfuscating or disrupting the standard behavior, are okay with me but I think iCal and AddressBook went off the deep end. :-D